# A few question about basic kivyMD| Why function in init are calling twice?| Why i don't see my buttons?|How add text to buttons?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

)

I'm  learn kivyMD and create simple app. I have many strange problems with that.

1. why my screen is black  and i can't see my button?
2. If i add 2 or more buttons (look at comment in code) i see error:

   ```
    kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.button.button.MDButton object at 0x00000202D8648E40>, it already has a parent <kivymd.uix.boxlayout.MDBoxLayout object at 0x00000202D86420B0>
   ```
3. How set button text in py?

   ```
   self.button = MDButton(style="filled",text='btn')
   ```

Doesn't work. Documentation tell about it how do it in kivy file.

4.  When i tried debug i noticed that my *init* is calling twice. Why? I completely don't know.

Can you explain me this basic things?

in main.py is:

```
#kivy=2.3.0
#kivymd=2.0.1
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager


class ExampleScreen(MDScreen):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print(1)
        super(ExampleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # ADDING STRUCTURAL ELEMENTS
        self.window = MDBoxLayout()
        self.button = MDButton(style="filled")
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)
        #self.window.add_widget(self.button)   unhash on 2 point
        #self.window.add_widget(self.button)   unhash on 2 point

class Screen_Menager(MDScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

MainApp().run()
```

My kv. file is simply: main.kv:

```
Screen_Menager:
    ExampleScreen:
```

And my output is:

```
INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Marek\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-01-26_64.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\pulpit\programowanie\Nice2meetU\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\pulpit\programowanie\Nice2meetU\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 2.0.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 2024-01-26 (installed at "D:\pulpit\programowanie\Nice2meetU\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.2114'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 31.0.101.2114'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: winctypes
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
1
1
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] Color scheme generation. Get a color scheme from an installed palette - 0.006442700000000023 sec.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to add the `MDBoxLayout` to your `MDScreen`. Try adding `self.add_widget(self.window)`. The error message is self explanatory. You cannot add the same widget more than once.

Comment: xd: I've rejected this idea because window is not widget :p But thanks it's work.

Comment: Do you know why prints in init launch twice? And how add text to MDButtons by python?

Answer (score 0):

`print` is called twice because your kivy file `main.kv` is loaded twice. When you name your app `SomethingApp`, Kivy will automatically load `something.kv`. So in your case, `main.kv` is loaded automatically.

You have two options to solve your issue:

1. Rename your app:

```py
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

MyApp().run()
```

2. Do not load `main.kv` explicitly:

```py
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"

MainApp().run()
```

Edit: sorry I neglected to answer your other questions. You're never adding `self.window` (poorly named layout btw) to your `ExampleScreen`. You should add it with `self.add_widget(self.window)`. Likewise, MDButtonText can be added to MDButton (see the [help](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/)):

```py
class ExampleScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print(1)
        super(ExampleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # ADDING STRUCTURAL ELEMENTS
        self.window = MDBoxLayout()
        self.button = MDButton(style="filled")
        self.button.add_widget(MDButtonText(text='btn text'))
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)
        self.add_widget(self.window)
```

I personnally prefer to declare structural elements in the .kv file directly (the width of your button will better fit in this case):

```
Screen_Menager:
    ExampleScreen:
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDButton:
                style: "filled"
                MDButtonText:
                    text: "btn text"
```